# Vista 64 bit compatibility mode in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

I've installed Vista 7 RC x64 and trying to install Vista 64 bit drivers for my HP LaserJet 1022.
I supose vista drivers should be fine for 7.

The problem is that the driver installer is checking the os info and won't start on Windows 7 (The package is not intended for windows 7 64 bit).
But when I'm giving it Vista in the compatibility settings now it appears as Vista 32bit to the installer and it won't run because it is 32 bit.

Is there any workaround for this compatibility problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific problem, you could try to unpack the installer yourself. Use for example WinRAR, and open the exe installer file with it, and extract all the content in a folder.

You will have your drivers there, with the inf file, etc, so you could install printer from this directly. (If more details are needed, don't hesitate to ask).

(Yes, I downloaded the actual installer to try, it works with this one. Haven't tried installing though)

Comment: Thanks! Now I have the driver installed and printer working. My original download wasn't actually the vista 64bit driver, but the driver instller would also fail (for a different reason), so I just unpacked the installer and the installer inside it and updated the printr device's driver pointing to the unpacked folder.